# Use two arrays to get variable and value ($key = $value) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$cfields = array_filter(explode(",", get_option('CComment_fields')));
$Ctlds = array_filter(explode(",", get_option('Ctlds')));
```

Sorry, I know this is a mess.  Basically I end up with two arrays: `$cVal` & `$Ctlds`

The arrays:

```
$Cval = Array ( [0] => Fun Co [1] => 555-555-5555 [2] => test@test.com [3] => Tom [4] => Smith ) 

$Ctlds = Array ( [0] => user_company [1] => user_phone [2] => user_email [3] => user_firstname [4] => user_lastname )
```

I want the matching `[NUMBER]` value in `$Ctlds` to be the variable with the matching `[NUMBER]` in `$Cval` to be the value.

Example:
user_company will be assigned the value Fun Co
user_phone will be assigned the value 555-555-5555
etc..

This is the code I tried - bad, I know.

```
foreach ($Ctlds as $Ctlds){
        $cVal[] = $Ctlds[];
    }
```

I have tried code I know is waaaayy off.  Any help would be appreciated.  And for search reference this is USING TO ARRAYS TO CREATE VARIABLE (KEYS) AND VALUES IN PHP.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the negative vote?  I am trying my best - we all start somewhere.

Comment: I did edit your post, I think someone downvoted because of the bad layout. Take a read here about styling in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  Good luck with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).  That's exactly what it's for.

```
$result = array_combine($Ctlds, $Cval);
```

If you want them to be variables, you can then just [`extract`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) that array.

Comment: Didn't knew about this one. Far better than reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of what you want, but you should try this :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($Ctlds as $key => $Ctld) {
    $result[$Ctld] = $Cval[$key];
}
```

You will get an array like :

```
Array (
    [user_company] => 'Fun Co',
    [user_phone] => '555-555-5555',
    [user_email] => 'test@test.com',
    [user_firstname] => 'Tom',
    [user_lastname] => 'Smith'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try delimiting your arrays with commas and escaping your strings. Ex:

Ex:

```
$Cval = array (
    [0] => "Fun Co",
    [1] => "555-555-5555",
    [2] => "test@test.com",
    [3] => "Tom",
    [4] => "Smith" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
foreach ($Ctlds as $key => $Ctld) {
    $$Ctld = $Cval[$key];
}
```

will result in :

```
$user_company = "Fun Co";
$user_phone = "555-555-5555";

etc
```